# Autotrophy vs. Heterotrophy in Chemotrophs

Tags: cell-biology

What's the difference between chemoautotrophs and chemoheterotrophs? They do both get their energy from high-energy inorganic particles, right?

Answer (score 1):

"Auto" vs "hetero" in general refers to if they can generate their energy independently or require the consumption of another living thing to generate their energy [Introductory Biology, 2.18](https://bio.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Introductory_and_General_Biology/Introductory_Biology_(CK-12)/02%3A_Cell_Biology/2.18%3A__Autotrophs_and_Heterotrophs). In the case of chemotrophs, they gather energy from chemical reactions that are not photosynthesis. The auto & hetero here refer to their ability to synthesize organic molecules on their own, instead of energy [Microbiology, LibreTexts 5.1B](https://bio.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Microbiology/Microbiology_(Boundless)/05%3A_Microbial_Metabolism/5.01%3A_Types_of_Metabolism/5.1B%3A_Chemoautotrophs_and_Chemohetrotrophs).